# When are county court decisions binding upon the “London region” of the county court?

Tags: england-and-wales, rules-of-court, precedent, county-court

And what unites or defines the “London region”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

County court decisions don't have binding authority.

HM Courts & Tribunals Service defines the regions.

For convenience, here are maps of locations of the HMCTS estates for the London region - I don't know how current the locations are, but the maps provide an idea of the regions covered.

[image: Map of London Region - Civil, Family and Tribunals][image: Map of London Region - Crime]

Source: [HMCTS Estate by Region and County](https://consult.justice.gov.uk/digital-communications/transforming-court-tribunal-estate/supporting_documents/hmctsnationalmap.pdf)

[The National Audit Office has an HM Courts & Tribunals estate interactive visualisation](https://www.nao.org.uk/reports/hm-courts-tribunals-estate-visualisation/). This "displays the HM Courts & Tribunals Service (HMCTS) estate, how it has changed from 2015 to March 2019 and where closures have taken place." You can zoom into the London region or other regions.